# BULK INSERT issues with SQL Server 2012 and higher releases

Tags: sql-server, bulkinsert

We work with a 3rd party and they provide us files that are basically a dump from their DB. Our company supports SQL Server 2012 as well as SQL Server 2014 and up. I need to BULK INSERT these files and have ONE set of files work for any client.

They provide us the files, from a UNIX system, as utf-8 encoded. I am aware that SQL Server 2012 doesn't support utf-8. From reading on here, I have gone the route of converting those files to utf-16 (using Textpad8). In total there are about 22 files.

I use the following syntax:

```
BULK INSERT database.dbo.tablename 
FROM '\\server\filename.txt' 
WITH (FIRSTROW =2, ROWTERMINATOR ='0x0a')
```

That of course works for all the files on SQL Server 2014 box.

ONE file of the 22 does NOT work for SQL Server 2012 and I cannot figure out what is wrong. That particular file goes into a table defined this way:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Map]
(
    termid int NOT NULL,
    mapguid char(22) NOT NULL,
    mapsequence int NOT NULL,
    conceptguid char(22) NOT NULL,
    mapdefnguid char(22) NOT NULL,
    mapquality int NULL, 

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Map] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([termid] ASC, [mapguid] ASC, [mapsequence] ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY];
```

This is what the sample data looks like

```
termid  mapguid mapsequence conceptguid mapdefnguid mapquality
260724  Nm9T2QFFs67xk2/zCgEDHw  0   AExH2wEce5u4wbhnqf4ZgQ  TDMQWQE6UQdXAoATCgECyQ  
172288  AW8L6AEj+br0hsZ3CgEBig  0   BgCTWgDjf6OlTk1oCwsLDQ  AUKoDQEjn6KrxIAJCgEBmw  
377707  PtArUQE7q1ajeoiRCgEDAQ  0   ACSYtQDsdrQtN1h2qf79/w  TDMQWQE6UsYdrYAbCgECeg
```

tab is column separator, and LF is the rowterminator character

This is the error I get:

> Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 2, column 1 (termid).
>
> Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 3, column 1 (termid).

I've searched that error on google (and here) and have seen where you may get that error if something is actually specified as literally 'NULL' instead of being blank.

I've even gone so far as to create my own file and I still get the same errors. In my own file, I actually populate the last row, thinking maybe that was causing issues, but the error seems to indicate it doesn't like something with the very first column.

Can anyone help me with some suggestions please?

Comment: Can you post your sample file contents and BCP command?

Comment: I can't really post the file, its over 500 MB, but I did post a sample of the data, above.  Similarly, I posted the BULK INSERT syntax above, not using BCP for this

Comment: There's something in the file that's not surviving the paste into the question body.

Comment: are you referring to seeing the actual column and row terminators? One of my thoughts was that mapquality column is null in the file, and I have seen thru research that sometimes that causes the error noted...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is REALLY an answer, but somehow, the file imports fine with utf-8 encoding, which doesn't make a lot of sense to me since SQL 2012 isn't supposed to support that. I looked at the data in the table and it appears to be fine, so I don't really have an explanation there.

I then converted the file to utf-16 and re-ran the process and started getting the above errors again, so...*shrug*

Comment: UTF-8 is indistinguishable from an ASCII or native code page encoding in most cases (as they have ASCII as a subset), save for the possible inclusion of the byte-order mark at the beginning. This BOM is standard on Windows, but typically omitted on Unixen (so that there's no way to know if the encoding used is UTF-8 except through context). If the file includes no characters that can't be encoded in ASCII, a UTF-8 file with no BOM *is* a plain ASCII file and will import. (If there are characters that can't be encoded in ASCII, you'll get [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake).)

Comment: I can tell you, in house, that we have one box where SQL 2012 is running service pack 3 and another is running service pack 4, and the service pack 4 box will not import ANY utf-16 files, it complains as above in very initial post for each file...and the initial post was from the box on service pack 3, where it only seemed to complain about 1 file.